# Irrealis “were” following “as if”

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, historical-change, language-evolution, irrealis-were

Is the subjunctive “were” in the sentence, “He seems as if he were spell-bound,” construed as counterfactual? Does it always preclude truth, or does it only here suggest that it was highly improbable that the subject, “he,” was spell-bound?

If I exchanged a past-conditional “was” for the “were” would it open possibilities in the sentence? And would a present indicative “is” make any sense at all? The present tense doesn’t seem to me well fitted to the phrase “as if.”

And if I could ask a question further: when were these distinctions drawn between “were,” “was,” and “is” regarding the phrase “as if”?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: All tenses are possible in this construction (**were**, **was**, **is**, and **will be**), so *were* is not being used as a subjunctive in this case. (*"Whoa, buddy. **It seems as if you're drunk.** Can I give you a hand?"*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “He seems as if he were spell-bound,” construed as counterfactual?

1. It **seems** to be the case - this is not the same as "it is the case".
2. "as if he were" approximates to "that he might be"

The speaker is expressing a possible description/explanation by comparing the subject's condition to a recognisable condition.

> Does it always preclude truth,

No. The speaker's guess could be correct.

> or does it only here suggest that it was highly improbable that the subject, “he,” was spell-bound?

This would depend upon the context. *(It is difficult to express how important context is in English)* (i) It may be probable if the subject were the prisoner of a wizard, then it is quite possible that he is spellbound - although the subjunctive and "seems" allow for other possibilities. (ii) If the subject were a modern businessman, as there is no such thing as magic, then the subject is not "spellbound" other than, perhaps in a figurative sense.

TO ADD

> when were these distinctions drawn between “were,” “was,” and “is” regarding the phrase “as if”?

Old English had the subjunctive.