# Subjunctive and Ellipsis/Syllepsis

Tags: subjunctive-mood, ellipses, syllepsis

Reading *Fowler’s Dictionary of Modern English Usage*, I came across this sentence under “subjunctive mood:” “It was as if Sally were disturbed in some way and was translating this disturbance into the habit of thought—A. Brookner, 1986 (UK).”

Am I to understand the subjunctive ends above with the past progressive “was translating”? Otherwise wouldn’t the subjunctive “were” apply and the phrase begin “were translating”?

Comment: Yes. I read the sentence as  “It was as if Sally were disturbed in some way and *, assuming that to be true, she* was translating this ..."

Comment: You could be right, Greybeard.  But (a) we need a larger context to be sure what the sentence means.  It could mean more than one thing.  So ‘disturbed’ might mean ‘was in a disturbed mental state’ or ‘had just been disturbed (by a jazz bend starting a rehearsal next doit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Irrealis “were” following “as if”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536136/irrealis-were-following-as-if)

Comment: It looks like the person swapped allegiance out of the 'were is necessary' school mid-sentence.